# how to show that the radio button is selected permanently

Tags: android, radio-button

i have the same problem as 
[how to show the radio button is selected is still ticked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198859/how-to-show-the-radio-button-is-selected-is-still-ticked) but in android platform... can anybody help me please..
my codes are

```
<RadioButton
android:checked="false"
android:id="@+id/BBC"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#ffff6600"
android:text="BBC NEWS"
android:typeface="serif"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_x="10px"
android:layout_y="100px">
</RadioButton>
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A question with similar content was asked yesterday:
[I have radio button for the user to choose if he/she wants to keep his/her account logged in.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314670/i-have-radio-button-for-the-user-to-choose-if-he-she-wants-to-keep-his-her-accoun)

you can't solve this problem just with the layout.xml - you need to save the status of the radio button and load it again once the appropriate activity is started

Answer (score 1):

You could save the value (when [changed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html)) to [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), read it each time the page is loaded, and [set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html#toggle%28%29) the checked state based on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static variable like is_ticked & set its value true/false when user tick it.   and check value of this variable in onCreate() if(is_ticked) set radio button to checked else unchecked .

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

`mListView.setItemChecked(selectedPosition, true);//this will check(enable) the desired radio button.`

selectedPosition, you can save using SharedPreferences.